# D3.js Collapsible tree - Show more than only name of node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I and using collapsible tree as shown in this link http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083 and I need to display details of each nodes. Here its only showing name. Any example or any link??

Comment: you can add multiple text just as you are adding a single text to the node(as in teh example)..same way nothing new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append new text elements for each additional information and adjust the dy positions to place them suitably. Also don't forget to use `selectAll` instead of `select` for updating `fill-opacity` of text elements during collapse/expand actions.

```js
var flare = {
 "name": "flare",
  "info1": "flare subtext 1",
  "info2": "flare subtext 2",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "info1": "analytics subtext 1",
   "info2": "analytics subtext 2",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "info1": "cluster subtext 1",
     "info2": "cluster subtext 2",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938,"info1": "AgglomerativeCluster subtext 1","info2": "AgglomerativeCluster subtext 2"}    
     ]
    },    
    {
     "name": "optimization",
         "info1": "optimization subtext 1",
   "info2": "optimization subtext 2",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074,"info1": "AspectRatioBanker subtext 1","info2": "AspectRatioBanker subtext 2"}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "animate",
       "info1": "animate subtext 1",
   "info2": "animate subtext 2",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010,"info1": "Easing subtext 1","info2": "Easing subtext 2"}        
   ]
  }
 ]
};
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  root = flare;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);


d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", "-.75em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
  
    nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", "1.00em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.info1; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
  
      nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", "2.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.info2; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.selectAll("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.selectAll("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Here in the data selection we are using directly with the name (i.e `d.children` ) . Can we use any function? something like `d.getChildren(index_number)` ?? So that we should not hardcode the children or subnode name as in data?